# Question regarding conditional probabilities with a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$

Tags: probability

The question is:
Packages arrive at a dstiribution center with parameter $\lambda$/hr. Find the probability that no package has arrived at the distribution center by 5pm given exactly 2 packages have arrived by 8pm. Opening time is 0pm.

So I guess this is how it should be:
X(t) = packages arrived at time t
then I need to find P(X(5) = 0 | X(8) = 2). But I do not know how to continue from here. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on when the store opened, if the store opened at 8am then you won't have $X(5)$ in the first argument. Otherwise, to calculate a conditional probability you can use Bayes theorem

Comment: I think the opening time is 0pm, so at 5pm 5 hours have past.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Yes, we have

$$ P(X(5)=0|X(8)=2) =\frac{P(X(5) =0 \cap X(8)=2)}{P(X(8)=2)} 
$$ $$=\large{\begin{align}\frac{e^{5\lambda}\cdot \frac{(5\lambda)^0}{0!}\cdot e^{3\lambda}\cdot \frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!}}{e^{8\lambda}\cdot \frac{(8\lambda)^2}{2!}}\end{align}} $$

I think you can take it from here.